# Add privilege_type to the privilege API results

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2

The [`/me/privileges`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-privileges), [`/users/{id}/privileges`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges-on-users) and [`/privileges`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges) APIs are currently returning the fields of `reputation`, `description` and `short_description`.

Sample result as:

```
{
    "reputation": 1,
    "description": "Ask a question or contribute an answer",
    "short_description": "create posts"
},
```

Since we have the following privilege types:

- Milestone
- Moderation
- Communication
- Creation
- Documentation *(Currently in Stack Overflow only)*

In any of the APIs, I'm not able to get the **privilege type**. So adding the `privilege_type` also to the current result is my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

So the expected result will be:

```
{
    "reputation": 1,
    "description": "Ask a question or contribute an answer",
    "short_description": "create posts",
    "privilege_type": "communication"
},
```